# Do we guess the cut off frequency when passband edge frequency and stop band edge frequency are given? FIR Filter design-LOW PASS FILTER

Tags: filters, lowpass-filter, finite-impulse-response, window-functions, window

Say passband edge frequency=0.25 $\pi$

Stopband edge frequency=0.35 $\pi$

What is the cut off frequency? Do we average these 2 frequencies and write the answer or what is the procedure to find cut off frequency?

This is the question I want to solve-:

Use hamming window method to design a digital low pass filter with pass band edge frequency=0.25$\pi$, stopband edge frequency=0.35$\pi$ where main lobe width of hanning window is 8*$\pi$/M M is filter length.

Comment: If the filter is FIR then it's the arithmetic mean, if it's of an IIR-type then it's the geometric mean.

Comment: First you have to define what you *mean* by "cut-off frequency". If you don't say "$X$ dB cut-off" for some $X$ (e.g., $3$dB) then the term has no clearly defined meaning. There's no reason why "cut-off frequency" shouldn't be the same as "pass band edge".

Comment: The question is-:Use hamming window method to design a digital low pass filter with pass band edge frequency=0.25pi, stopband edge frequency=0.35pi where main lobe width of hanning window is 8pi/M M is filter length. @MattL.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In the windowing design method for FIR filters, the impulse response for the desired frequency response filter is selected with a window. Typically the desired frequency response is a rectangular function in frequency (a brickwall filter, pass a group of frequencies and block the rest), in which case the ideal impulse response is a Sinc function. In this case, the transition in the frequency response maps to a -6 dB cutoff after the windowing operation which will be half way between a passband edge frequency and stopband edge frequency.

The graphic below demonstrates this for a rectangular window. For other windows, the transition band will increase for a given number of taps, but the relationship between $f_c$ in the desired rectangular frequency response  and $f_c$ that is midway in the transition band still applies.

[image: rectangular window]

For other design methods such as Parks-McClellan and Least Squares, the passband edge and stopband edge is provided to the design algorithm. The resulting 6 dB cutoff will similarly be half way between the passband edge and stopband edge. Generally it needs to be clarified as to what we mean by "cut-off" as this can refer to a -3 dB cutoff or -6 dB cutoff (or any dB cutoff).